# Reload .flexslider on resize

Tags: jquery, reload, flexslider

I am adding a class .flexslider around a div that wraps li tags containing images, my function adds it when the window is less than 767px. The slider A. only works when resized and not on .ready, also when screen scrolls greater than 767px I remove the .flexslider class but the slider still initiates.

```
  function bannerSlider() {
     "use strict";
      if ($(window).width() < 767) {              
           $("#activate-slider").addClass('flexslider');
           $("#activate-slider > ul").addClass('slides');   
       } else if ($Query(window).width() > 767) {       
           $("#activate-slider").removeClass('flexslider');
           $("#activate-slider > ul").removeClass('slides');
       } 

   }
```

When Window is 767px or more the HTML code looks like this

```
       <div id="activate-slider">
          <ul>  
          <li>myimage</li>
          <li>myimage</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

When Window is 767px or LESS the HTML code looks like this

```
       <div id="activate-slider" class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">   
          <li>myimage</li>
          <li>myimage</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Quick Recap, want the slider to initate if window (mobile devices) screen is LESS than 767px, NOT just on resize, I can review my code and find where i went wrong there most likely, the main issue is DEACTIVATING the slider when window goes back ABOVE 767px.

I run my function inside document.ready window.resize & tried inside window.load
Logically I can see where it is not running the way I would like, but I can't figure out what to write to make to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pausing / playing the flexslider?

```
function bannerSlider() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(window).width() <= 767) {              

       $("#activate-slider").addClass('flexslider');
       $("#activate-slider > ul").addClass('slides'); 

       if ( $('.flexslider').flexslider('animating') == false ) {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider('play') ; 
       }

  } 
  else if ($Query(window).width() > 767) {       

       if ( $('.flexslider').flexslider('animating') == true ) {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider('pause') ;
       }

       $("#activate-slider").removeClass('flexslider');
       $("#activate-slider > ul").removeClass('slides');
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in js of flexslider

find-> slider.doMath approximately 950-960 line in none minified version

then add code below

the maxItems and
before slider.w
snipet

```js
 var w = $(window).width();
                var h = $(window).height();
                console.log("w " + w);
                console.log("h " + h);
                if (w > 1025) {
                    maxItems = slider.vars.maxItems;
                }
                else if (w = 1020) {
                    maxItems = 3;
                }
                else if (w >= 568) {
                    maxItems = 2;
                }
                else if (568 > w) {
                    maxItems = 1;
                }
```